# Is there a way to see how many covenant items I have turned in?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I'm farming for covenant items in order to get the rank rewards (spells & items).  Is there a way to see how many I've turned in already to the covenant vendor/master so I know how many more I need?

I know it's 10 for the first reward and 30 for the next reward, but I lost count and neglected to just hold them in my inventory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found three different posts asking the same or at least a similar question as you:

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls3/comments/4f3qea/is_there_a_way_to_check_your_covenant_ranks/)
- [GameFAQs 1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168566-dark-souls-iii/73614095)
- [GameFAQs 2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168566-dark-souls-iii/73639155)

The last link no one mentioned that its possible or not, but in the other two, they say that they haven't found a way to check.  It seems like in [Dark Souls 2 there wasn't a way](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168566-dark-souls-iii/74621163) either.

Answer (score 2):

The only covenant you can keep track of your progress is the Blades of the Darkmoon. There's a roster item that you can use to see how many Proofs of Concord Kept you've turned in. There is no similar item for the other covenants.

Comment: Would downvote if I could, too vague "a roster item". What item and where to find it?

Comment: Its called "Roaster of Kights" and its found from Church of Yorshka bonfire - down the stairs first right in the corner hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There never has been a way in-game to keep track of covenant items, in any of the games. This is also true for Dark Souls 3.

The only way to keep track is to either keep them in your inventory, or keep track  yourself.